# What algorithm would I use to create a grade based on 3 numeric attributes?

Tags: ranking

I'm currently using Weka to prototype some possible applications for machine learning. One such application is a grade based on the performance of a user's mailing list. I have the following attributes:

```
   Attribute  |   Type
-----------------------------
List Name     | Nominal
Total Sent    | Numeric
Total Opened  | Numeric
Total Clicked | Numeric
```

My goal is to break up the data set into 9 categories, one for each grade (A+ to C-), but I'm not sure which algorithm I would use, or the proper parameter to begin prototyping.

Here's what some of the data looks like:

```
 List   |   Sent  |  Opened | Clicked 
--------------------------------------
list 1  |  51587  |  17251  |  1787
list 2  |  22128  |  8538   |  815
list 3  |  211007 |  24803  |  1719
list 4  |  12910  |  1530   |  183
list 5  |  148054 |  41171  |  0
list 6  |  182392 |  17579  |  1749
list 7  |  68212  |  4765   |  447
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to decide how you want to assign the grades.  You might want to think about what properties do you think should correspond to higher grades.  This doesn't seem like a machine learning problem in its current form, it's just a matter of choosing an evaluation metric.

If you had labelled data (for some mailing lists you had grades assigned) then you consider consider applying supervised learning methods.  Without that, there's nothing for a ML algorithm to get a foothold with.